# C#: Error when HttpClient reponse

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, httpclient

I am doing HTTP get request using `HttpClient` in C# console app . I am not getting expected response with one get request.

Get Request is like 
http://example.com/xyz/SearchProduct?productNo=11210&1d6rstc9xc=5jyi27htzk

I am getting some vague response but when i do same get request with fiddler it is giving expected response.

How can I get expected response from httpClient.GetAsync(url)?

code is :-

```
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var url = "http://example.com/xyz/SearchProduct?productNo=11210&1d6rstc9xc=5jyi27htzk";

            HttpResponseMessage response1 = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

            if (response1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                HttpContent stream = response1.Content;
                Task<string> data = stream.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }
```

Comment: Show code, if you want help.

Comment: @mybirthname - code is added

Comment: `var r = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);`
`var result = await r.Content.ReadAsAsync<YourType>()`
(ReadAsAsync is an extention method by NewtonSoft

Comment: So did you check if my solution is working ?

Answer (score 0):

You should read as string that way:

```
string result = await stream.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

instead of that:

```
Task<string> data = stream.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

[Here full code example](http://rextester.com/discussion/XPKY90132/async-example-with-HttpClient) and [another example](https://www.dotnetperls.com/httpclient)

Answer (score 0):

This is a full method using **async/await** approach.

```
   private static async Task<string> GetRequestContentAsString(string url)
    {
        var data = string.Empty;

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var stream = response.Content;
                data = await stream.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }

        return data;
    }
```

This method is called this way:

```
var content = await GetRequestContentAsString("http://www.bing.com");
```